# how to setTitle in blackberry dynametically?

Tags: blackberry, title

I want to change the title of blackberry application view again and again when certain condition gets true, how can I do it?

Right now I am doing as

```
BitmapField loading=new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("loading.png"));
this.setTitle(loading);
```

but now I want something else on title, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

In [MainScreen.setTitle](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html#setTitle%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field%29) you can use any Field - LabelField or BitmapField or even CheckboxField :) actually, anything.

But remember to [handle UI thread when updating UI from other threads](http://thinkingblackberry.com/?p=182).